# How can I start the line numbering of my listing by an arbitrary number?

Tags: listings, line-numbering

This is what I want:

```
15  <servlet>
16    <servlet-name>udpListener</servlet-name>
17    <servlet-class>oli.servlet.UdpServlet</servlet-class>
18    <!-- UDP Port fuer MSX -->
19    <init-param>
20      <param-name>udpPort</param-name>
21      <param-value>4951</param-value>  <!--Empfangsport-->
22    </init-param>
23    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
24  </servlet>
```

I want that line numbering starts at an number other than 1.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 36):

The listings package [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) has an example that covers this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=100]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question with the example you provided:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=15]
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>udpListener</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>oli.servlet.UdpServlet</servlet-class>
  <!-- UDP Port fuer MSX -->
  <init-param>
    <param-name>udpPort</param-name>
    <param-value>4951</param-value>  <!--Empfangsport-->
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
\end{lstlisting}
```

And if you set `[firstnumber=last]` in a listing, the listing will continue to count line numbers where the previous listing stopped.